# XPath 1.0 return node with two conditons

Tags: xpath

My current XPath returns `ancestor-or-self` nodes matching criteria.

```
//*[contains(., '"& v_search &"')]/ancestor-or-self::*/*[local-name()='name' and @locale='en']
```

Now I want to implement addition feature to return `following-sibling` from the matching nodes. I have changed my XPath as below. But it doesn't return ancestor-or-self plus sibling in result.

```
//*[contains(., '"& v_search &"')]/ancestor-or-self::*/following-sibling::*/*[local-name()='name' and @locale='en']
```

here v_search is a variable that can be replaced by any string for testing.
My xml is like :-

```
<root xmlns="https://jlkjsdlfjl/">
    <name>Accounts</name>
    <property name="included" type="hidden">true</property>
    <locales>
        <locale>en</locale>
        <locale>de</locale>
    </locales>
    <defaultLocale>en</defaultLocale>
    <searchspace>
        <name locale="en">Accounts</name>
        <name locale="de">Accounts</name>
        <lastChanged>2014-03-05T18:47:30</lastChanged>
        <lastChangedBy>userx</lastChangedBy>
        <property name="included" type="hidden">true</property>
        <searchspace>
            <name locale="en">Database L</name>
            <name locale="zw">Database L</name>
            <searchSubject status="valid">
                <name locale="en">SName1</name>
                <name locale="zw">qskxyz</name>
                <searchItem>
                    <name locale="en">IName1</name>
                    <name locale="zw">qixyz</name>
                    <hello>v_search</hello>
                </searchItem>
                 <searchItem>
                    <name locale="en">IName2</name>
                    <name locale="zw">abc</name>
                    v_search
                </searchItem>
                 <searchItem>
                    <name locale="en">IName3</name>
                    <name locale="zw">def</name>
                    <hello>something else</hello>
                </searchItem>
            </searchSubject>
        </searchspace>
    </searchspace>
    <searchspace>
        <name locale="en">Names</name>
        <lastChanged>2016-01-12T12:42:46</lastChanged>
        <searchspace>
            <name locale="en">Database Layer</name>
            <name locale="zw">Database Layer</name>
            <searchSubject status="valid">
                <name locale="en">SName2</name>
                <searchItem>
                    <name locale="en">IName4</name>
                    <hello>...Hi there..</hello>
                </searchItem>
            </searchSubject>
        </searchspace>
    </searchspace>
</root>
```

v_search is sample keyword, I want to return sibling of lowest matching nodes.
i.e. sibling of self from `ancestor-or-self`.

Comment: Currently, it isn't clear `following-sibling` of which element that you mean; `following-sibling` of matching element or `following-sibling` of ancestor of matching element?

Comment: Maybe it will help if you provide sample keyword and elements you expect to be selected given that keyword and the above XML..

Comment: I have added last line with edit

Comment: Alright, that sounds clearer. But now my confusion is, that the matching element (`<hello>v_search</hello>`) in the given scenario doesn't have any `following-sibling`. So, what element(s) do you *actually* mean by `following-sibling` of the `v_search` element here?

Comment: IName2 has matching value `v_search` and it also has a sibling following it IName3. So the result should be `ancestor-or-self of IName2` and sibling of IName2 that is IName3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way might be to introduce 2nd expression that will return '`following-sibling`' of the matched element. You can combine the 2nd expression with the existing one using union (`|`) operator as follow (wrapped for readability) :

```
//*[contains(., 'v_search')]
 /ancestor-or-self::*
 /*[local-name()='name' and @locale='en']
    |
//*[text()[contains(.,'v_search')]]
 /following-sibling::*
 /*[local-name()='name' and @locale='en']
```

Brief test : http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/294a1ef49d30eb6abecf2f024cfcd318